# Scala implicit converters

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to figure out how to create an implicit converter for a particular type. In my case, that would be a `Set[IdParam[T]]` to a `Set[IdTag[T]]`, where

```
import shapeless.tag.@@

case class IdParam[T](value: IdTag[T])
type IdTag[T] = Id @@ T

class Id(val value: Long)
object Id {
  def tag[T](l: Long) = shapeless.tag[T][Id](new Id(l))

  def value[T](l: Long) = Id.tag[T](l)
}
```

I wrote a simple

```
implicit def toIds[T](idParams: Set[IdParam[T]]): Set[IdTag[T]] = idParams.map(_.value)
```

which works OK. But my main question now is if there is a way to create an implicit converter which would cover both Seq and Set. Going up the hierarchy, that would mean an Iterable.
Tried the following

```
implicit def toIds[I <: Iterable[IdParam[T]], T](idParams: I): Iterable[IdTag[T]] = idParams.map(_.value)
```

The compiler refuses to accept this converter where it's needed.

```
[error]  found   : Set[tags.IdParam[tags.ProfileIdTag]]
[error]  required: Set[tags.ProfileId]
[error]     (which expands to)  Set[model.Id with shapeless.tag.Tagged[tags.ProfileIdTag]]
```

EDIT
That implicit converter should be used in the Controller endpoint.

```
GET     /campaigns @dummy.Campaigns.all(profileId: Set[IdParam[ProfileIdTag]] ?= Set.empty)
```

I have a QueryStringBindable which converts the query param retrieved as a string into a `Set[IdParam[A]]`

```
object IdQueryStringBinder {
  implicit def idParamQueryStringBinder[A](implicit stringBinder: QueryStringBindable[String]) =
new QueryStringBindable[IdParam[A]] {

    def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, IdParam[A]]] =
      for {
        idEither <- stringBinder.bind(key, params)
      } yield {
        idEither match {
          case Right(idString) =>
            IdBinder.parseIdString(idString)
          case Left(_) => Left("Unable to bind an Id")
        }
      }

    override def unbind(key: String, id: IdParam[A]): String =
      stringBinder.unbind(key, id.value.toString)
  }

  implicit def idsParamQueryStringBinder[A](implicit stringBinder: QueryStringBindable[String]) =
    new QueryStringBindable[Set[IdParam[A]]] {
      override def bind(key: String, params: Map[String, Seq[String]]): Option[Either[String, Set[IdParam[A]]]] = {
        stringBinder.bind(key, params).map(_.right.flatMap(parse))
      }

      private def parse(idsString: String): Either[String, Set[IdParam[A]]] = {
        val (wrongIds, correctIds) = idsString.split(",")
          .map(id => IdBinder.parseIdString[A](id))
          .partition(_.isLeft)
        if (wrongIds.nonEmpty) {
          Left(s"Could not bind the following Ids: ${wrongIds.map(_.left.get).mkString(",")}")
        } else {
          Right(correctIds.map(_.right.get).toSet)
        }
      }

      override def unbind(key: String, ids: Set[IdParam[A]]): String =
        stringBinder.unbind(key, ids.map(_.value.toString).mkString(","))
    }
}
```

My Controller is

```
class Campaigns extends play.api.mvc.Controller {
  def allByProfileId(profile: ProfileId) = ...
  def all(profileIds: Set[ProfileId]) = ...
}
```

The first endpoint works, which uses the defined `idParamQueryStringBinder` with the following implicit converter

```
implicit def toId[T](idParam: IdParam[T]): IdTag[T] = idParam.value
```

Comment: add code which error cause pls

Comment: This is where the error is being thrown from:  
    `[error] GET     /campaigns                                                              @dummy.Campaigns.all(profileId: Set[IdParam[ProfileIdTag]] ?= Set.empty)`

Answer (score 0):

You must have done some coding mistake because it works perfectly fine for me:
https://gist.github.com/kpbochenek/ce2a783d59a7bd28585e4cbf7a64cad4

next time paste full code that causes the issue not only small parts.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've added more details of the code. The @@ is taken from the shapeless library, not scalaz. Sorry I didn't mention that before.